# Every time Windows boots up I get asked to update Dropbox even though it isn't installed?

Tags: windows-10, boot, dropbox

[image]

Every time Windows boots up I get the above message even though Dropbox isn't installed. How do I stop it?

Comment: Windows 10 comes with Dropbox already installed as an app. you can uninstall it with this PowerShell command: `Get-AppxPackage *Dropbox* | Remove-AppxPackage`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran that in PowerShell (Admin), restarted and am still getting the same error

Comment: Have you checked the start up items to see if Dropbox is listed?

Comment: Use regedit and search for all items containing "dropbox".

Comment: How do you know it’s not installed? It comes pre-installed on certain OEM equipment. Click start -> settings -> system -> apps and features and remove it.

Comment: Does your computer have multiple users? Another user may have installed dropbox before the windows 10 upgrade and this is a residual effect. The other user should have dropbox mentioned in their Add/Remove programs section.

Comment: Try to search for Dropbox on your system to make sure if it is installed. not sure if the desktop app or metro app installed on your OS, but for metro app, we could uninstall it through Settings, for desktop app, go to control panel\program and feature to uninstall it. But if you can't find the app, we could use process monitor tool to enable boot process, and check where the location of this app

Answer (score 1):

Due to resetting Windows but keeping files, Dropbox was left in the AppData and Startup folders and as such kept displaying this message even though it wasn't installed. After removing Dropbox from those folders it fixed the problem. Thanks for the comments they helped me resolve it.